# Unable to query Google Cloud VM from Vercel

Tags: google-cloud-platform, networking, next.js, google-compute-engine, vercel

I have set up an API in a Google Cloud VM for a POC and opened the port 9090 using Firewall rules with IP ranges `0.0.0.0/0`, `Ingress`, `Allow`:

[image]

I can properly fetch my port from my local network (censured the IP):

> louisbeaumont@MacBook-Pro-4:~$ nc -zv  x.x.x.x 9090

> Connection to x.x.x.x port 9090 [tcp/websm] succeeded!

The same command also works from a Github Codespace (which runs somewhere in Azure I assume).

On the other hand, I cannot fetch the instance from a Vercel Edge Runtime API, receiving a 403 Forbidden upon running this code:

```
const generateText = async (...): Promise<...> => {
  // url being like http://x.x.x.x:9090
  const response = await fetch(url, {
    headers: {
      'Content-Type': 'application/json',
    },
    method: 'POST',
    body: JSON.stringify(payload),
  })
  if (!response.ok) {
    // here I receive a 403 Forbidden
    throw new Error('Network response was not ok' + response.statusText)
  }
  const responseJson = await response.json()
  return responseJson[0]
}
```

The same code works locally.

I really don't know what's wrong here, I guess it's an issue on Vercel side? Should I tweak some network configuration there? Maybe they forbid Egress towards some IP or HTTP is forbidden?

Comment: 1) You have created a VPC firewall rule allowing all traffic from anywhere. The firewall is not the cause of your problem. Note: that firewall rule is dangerous and should be tightened once you solve your problem. 2) `nc` is opening a TCP port. It is not using HTTP to connect. Opening a port is very different from an HTTP POST request. Most likely your backend code that is handling the POST request is rejecting the request. 3) Edit your post and show the code that is handling the HTTP POST request.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. I don't mind about security ATM. With a cURL it works too. `curl -X POST   http://x.x.x.x:9090   -H 'Content-Type: application/json'   -d '{...}'`

The code handling the request is the Docker image here https://github.com/huggingface/text-generation-inference but does not matter. The request works locally with fetch and not when deployed in vercel?

Comment: You need to debug the code that is handling the HTTP POST which is returning the 403. Your other assumptions are meaningless. I can give you suggestions, you must do the debugging.